Can a long enough series of numbers in the correct order be all there is to emergent consciousness?
It occurs to me that everything from the coding of DNA the action potential between neurons Etc can most definitely be Quantified and given sufficient data and compute possibly with the help of quantum computers (given recent discoveries of possible structures with Quantum properties in the brain) be simulated. It now occurs to me that large language models might be coming at this from just the other direction taking all of human output our brains interpretation and description of all of the things we feel see hear even imagine and dream of throughout time up till this point efficiently compressing all of this information might be a little off the mark if the Transformer algorithm is actually in some meaningful way reverse engineering human consciousness with incredibly High Fidelity and depth more clues to this come with the fact that it was recently discovered when we're looking for the next word to say you tokenize that information.. how many people believe large language models can ever be conscious or are they now?

The answer to your question partially hinges on whether quantum effects meaningfully contribute to cognition. As such, it can't be definitively answered yet. If quantum effects are required for cognition, then the Kochen-Specker theorem precludes their quantification.

There are no technical barriers to the creation of a digital copy of our reality some time in the future (Simulation Theory). But the question remains if this copy will show signs of life (energy of evolution).

Is the capitalization of Quantified, Quantum, and High Fidelity meaningful or spurious?

In philosophy you may read Kant's CPR for further inspiration about similar transcendental complexity and categorical ideas of relations without relata...

@DoubleKnot And David should read Ulysses in order to perfect his stream-of-consciousness [!] style ;-).

@Peter-ReinstateMonica that may be helpful after reading CPR to ensure a solid philosophical foundation first, btw Kant could be said to have a similar pure first-person style as that of James Joyce in terms of spitting out their next word...

Even if we grant the possibility that a large language model (or some other sufficiently advanced neural network) could become conscious, it's still the case that the dataset on its own wouldn't be conscious, any more than a dead human brain can be conscious.  For consciousness to occur, you would also need to have a computer present and executing the appropriate operations on that dataset -- consciousness is an ongoing activity, not just a state of being.

Didn't Victor Frankenstein already try this?

A series of numbers is an abstract object. In and of itself, such a series does not result in computation or effects in the world. Consciousness cannot emerge from a mere series.

What's the proof of your last sentence?

What empiricism can learn from Pygmalion: The map is not the terrain, and the model is not what's being modeled. This is a human dream, that we model something so perfectly it takes on the nature of the thing being modeled. That doesn't ever seem to happen (speaking empirically), but I respect the dream.
If large language models ever become conscious it will likely be in spite of our efforts, not because of them, and that carries its own list of worries. See Overly Sarcastic Production's Pygmalion and Galatea (mature themes and art, and deep sarcasm).

There are two problems with your question:

Not everything in our universe CAN be quantified.  There are irrational numbers in our universe that are incomputable.  For example, we only approximate Pi, and the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle insures that we cannot create a model of our universe down to the lowest level.

The assumption that consciousness must be identical to an algorithm, if only we can find that algorithm, is the core assumption of functionalism. Functionalism is not a MATERIAL identity theory, but an identity with abstracta (the series of numbers you refer to) and allows consciousness to exist in a frozen state in, say, an inert hard disk, or a code printout.


One problem with functionalism is that we and our machines do functions all the time without consciousness. This is a false positive for functional identity theory, and is also true for every variant of special classes of functions that have been proposed as a patch to the basic theory.
A second problem with functionalism is false negatives, where the more constrained esoteric function patches proposed are not present in all cases where we ARE conscious.
A third problem is that functions just do not match consciousness conceptually.  The thought problem challenges of the inverted rainbow, the Chinese room, and this question of frozen consciousness when all consciousness we know of is very dynamic, just show a radical incompatibility between functions and the nature of consciousness.
IF consciousness is identical to some function, AND all of the physical world can be functionalized, THEN your premise could be true.  But the preconditions are highly suspect.

Pi is not incomputable under the usual definition of that term (at least, the usual definition of that term in computer science). For truly incomputable numbers you need more exotic objects; Chaitin's number is the standard example here.

Whether pi is computable is irrelevant. The question involves whether the universe can be represented in terms of numbers, not whether the real numbers can be perfectly modeled by physical objects and phenomena.

@PaulTanenbaum If the ratio of a circumference to a radius can only ever be approximated, not computed exactly, is that not “the universe can not be fully represented in numbers”?

It boils down to the difference between “the universe” and “every conceivable true proposition about the universe.”

I would disagree with the premise that consciousness is an emergent property of material chemistry.  If by "emergent consciousness" we simply mean the expressions of consciousness in the material realm, I would say possibly yes, a computer may some day be able to immitate consciousness well enough.  But if consciousness is immaterial, such as a gift of God to the human soul, as I believe, and it merely expresses itself and operates in the material world, then material numbers alone in any sequence would not be able to reproduce that.
I think it might be similar to asking if we can reproduce the Grand Canyon with ink and paper alone.  We can produce a photograph, maybe realistic enough for all practical purposes; but that's not the same thing as building a new copy of the Grand Canyon itself.

Numbers are not material.  They are abstract objects, with neither mass nor location, nor time.  The questioner is assuming an "algorithmic identity theory" not a "chemical identity theory" between consciousness and some other substrate.  Additionally, answers here ask for consideration of a proposal on its own merits, not expressions of your own personal opinion.  See the help center on how to write a good answer:  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

@Dcleve--I may not have stated it clearly enough, but I meant not that numbers are themselves material, of course, but was pointing to numbers abstracted over material (as with LLMs, which run on physical computers).  If consciousness is a spiritual essence that is part of an immaterial soul, then it is not a mere abstraction over material, in the sense that numbers abstracted over the physical world are.  And in such a case, while we may be able to reproduce the image or impression that consciousness leaves in the material world, this would not be the same as reproducing consciousness itself.

Can we work with your question from the perspective of approximation? This would avoid an absolutist problem related to having to know the nature of quantification and quantifiability as far as we do know it. One can ask, rather, how quantifiable (or informational) biological and physical in general moments and/or processes can be understood as processional in the ontogeny of consciousness itself.
You can probably see where this leads. Are you suggesting a single "genome of consciousness" that is repeated in each case? Why? Why would a single procession or formula of procession, or even set of processions, be the case?
Given a fearlessness re: complexity, why couldn't each consciousness be as unique, if similarly founded, as our fingerprints?
This de facto (approximate) incommensurability of consciousnesses would explain a lot of issues in philosophy of language, it seems to me. Consciousness is itself an approximation, not a complete, sequence, that does not repeat across instances, and moreover, is not teleologically organized, as a reflection of its open nature. In such a context, language is itself an approximation of an open set of approximate systems.
One can gamble a poetic illumination, and suggest that consciousness perpetually "fails" or "depletes itself" because it is always in procession and language in turn, is always therefore a failed or depleting enterprise.
So in short, 1) no need for a Laplacian outcome, since both quantification and consciousness are depletive processions, open, and approximate, and 2) I think your question should go all in. We each are a completely distinct approximate sequence. Consciousness is as distinct as a fingerprint, or I would guess, rather more even. This is no problemo because 3) our languages, which appear to unite or unify consciousness, are all just so many McGuffins. Not really the point, and good, because they are not satisfying, being only approximations in every case.

On a beautiful day in June we, children, would sometimes lie in the grass, looking up at the billowing white cumulus clouds, high above, slowly drifting past. We were playing the game "watching tv" (since in those days nobody had a tv in our village) and would tell each other what we saw: a giant puppy, a dragon, a boat.
If you ask ChatGPT

Can a dialog system like ChatGPT ever become conscious (self-aware)?

it will tell you (among other things)

These systems do not possess understanding, beliefs, desires, or intentions. They operate purely on patterns learned from data.

A LLM is, obviously, not conscious. Used in a dialogue system the system is able to understand and answer certain questions by statistically generating a sequence of words that most likely is perceived as a reasonable answer. However, the system is also not conscious; it does not have internal mental states; it has no subjective experiences, perceptions, feelings, awareness, or self-awareness.
Or does it?
It has some memory (of the dialogue history). The memories will also contribute to setting the context for parsing new questions. It can meaningfully and correctly answer some questions about how it itself works. So, in that sense, it does have some kind of self-awareness or a self-model. This self-model might just be an epiphenomenon (so there is no identifiable part or component that is this self-model; having the model is just an alternative way to express the fact that it can correctly answer some questions about itself), but perhaps something similar also applies to human minds?
When we say that the system 'understands' the question - is that 'merely' a metaphorical way of speaking? Isn't the boundary between metaphorical and literal speech rather blurry here? Is there a hard demarcation line between what David Chalmers calls the "easy" problems of consciousness (how cognitive processes work) and the "hard" problems (how feelings and subjective states come to be and what they are)?
Or is it perhaps so that when we say the system 'understands' - what is relevant is not so much which objective properties that system has, but what is relevant is both how the system acts and how we interact with that?
There is a tantalizing little riddle about mirrors: When you look in a mirror, the mirror reverses left and right. But this is strange, since a mirror is just a sheet of glass that doesn't have prefences for any directions. So, why does a mirror reverse left and right and not (say) up and down?
I learned the answer reading Douglas Hofstadter. The mirror doesn't reverse left/right or up/down, it merely reflects; it only reverses front and back. What we see - our left/right reversed mirror image - is the result of projecting ourselves onto the mirror image and it's a lot easier to do a my-left-to-his-right reversal than a my-up-to-his-down one, for obvious reasons.
We don't have direct access to other minds - the minds of other homo sapiens individuals -, yet we believe they 'are conscious' ('have feelings', 'have perceptions', 'are self-aware'). Why? Doesn't this also involve some acts of projection - seeing ourselves in the other (based on some perceptual similarities)?
If attributing consciousness to other minds is based on projection, why not take yet another step: Is attributing consciousness (feelings, perceptions) to ourselves really different from attributing it to others? Perhaps I am a strange loop, as Hofstadter writes, a story this body tells itself, and this 'self' is perhaps like the projected image of itself (and of others), ever changing like the drifting clouds.
Anyway, our current dialogue systems are still far from coming close. Perhaps one of the missing components is constant adaptability, constant learning? Or lack of other perceptual modes? Lack of more ways of acting?
Most current systems are -- apart from limited use of contextual memory -- totally static; their LLM does not change but can only be retrained en bloc. There is some analogy with us too in that regard. It's really much harder for adult humans to learn a new natural language than for infants.
But given this kind of static core architecture, it's hard to imagine how this could bring about something close to actual consciousness.
So it may also be that we need very different architectures, for instance, Hopfield networks - which do seem to come closer to how our brains actually work.

The thing is that "they operate purely on patterns learned from data" is a perfectly valid description of humans as well. Honi soit qui mal y pense.
